# Django / haystack - faceting based only on the year element of a DateField

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack, datefield

Say I have the following model in a Django implementation:

```
class Broadcast(models.Model):
    broadcast_date = models.DateField()
    ...
```

In my haystack/Solr-driven search results, I'd like to be able to facet by solely the year of broadcast, not the exact day.

I could just make a new model attribute for this, but it seems like I should be able to do this in the search_indexes model definition somehow. Here is what I have in search_indexes.py at the moment, which facets by the full date only:

```
class BroadcastIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = [...]
    broadcast_date = indexes.DateField(model_attr="broadcast_date", faceted=True)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [date_facet()](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#date-facet). If you set it's `gap_by` parameter to `year`, it will facet by year.

Comment: That does seem like the right direction, but I'm not sure how to access the resulting data from a template. Is there a particular tag I need to use? Or do I need to parse that in the view code somewhere, and explicitly pass it along in the renderer as a new context variable?

Comment: Have a look at the example in the documentation https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html#display-the-facets-in-the-template

Comment: That is somewhat helpful, thanks. What they fail to mention is that the result of the date_facet() method is stored in facets.dates.[name_of_your_date_field]. They are also returned in the format yyyy-01-01:00:00:00, so you still have some text processing to do before you can display the year only. There also isn't any obvious way to actually filter your search by the returned date count data -- this is what I am struggling with at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an overview of what I ended up doing.

First over in my *urls.py* file I included a custom SearchQuerySet using `date_facet()` (thanks Adrian Ghiuta!), which I passed to my search view:

```
...
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

sqs = SearchQuerySet().date_facet('broadcast_date', start_date=date(1955, 1, 1), end_date=date(2015, 1, 1), gap_by="year")

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^search/', views.SarkSearch(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs), name='haystack_search'),
]
```

The `date_facet()` function does give a dictionary of faceted dates with year counts, but the returned keys are in the format yyyy-01-01:00:00:00, so I just ended up slicing the year out of that string. I used a list comprehension to create a new list with just the data I wanted, then I added that to the facets context variable. I was using a class-based view subclassing FacetedSearchView, so I needed to put all the processing code in the `extra_context()` function:

```
class FooSearch(FacetedSearchView):
    def extra_content(self):
        extra = super(FooSearch, self).extra_context()
        dates = extra['facets']['dates']['broadcast_date']
        dates = sorted([[year[:4], count] for year, count in dates.items() if count > 0])
        extra['facets']['dates']['broadcast_date'] = dates
        return extra
```

Now that I had the returned year facets, with counts, I needed to come up with a way to narrow the actual search results to only those within a given year. Over in my search template I bound each returned facet date to a facet link, using the GET variable "year_facet". That looked something like this:

```
<dl>
    {% if facets.dates.broadcast_date %}
        <dt>Broadcast dates</dt>
        {% for date in facets.dates.broadcast_date %}
            <dd><a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&amp;year_facet={{ date.0 }}">{{ date.0 }}</a> ({{ date.1 }})</dd>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if 'year_facet' in request.get_full_path %}
        <!-- I want a way to clear the facet if one is present -->
        <dd><a href="?q={{ query }}"><em>see all</em></a></dd>
    {% endif %}
</dl>
```

Now that the links were set up, I needed a way for my view to actually narrow the results when a year-based date facet was selected. To do that, back in my search view I overwrote the `get_results()` function to include date filters for all dates within the given year:

```
def get_results(self):
    if 'year_facet' in self.request.GET:
        year = int(self.request.GET['year_facet'])
        return self.form.search().filter(broadcast_date__lte=datetime.date(year, 12, 31)).filter(broadcast_date__gte=datetime.date(year, 1, 1))

    return self.form.search()
```

All together this worked pretty well.